# How to resolve pymysql.err.ProgrammingError?

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

Can't seem to figure out why I'm getting the error below for this python method in my script. I can't really post the full method here but it's erroring out at the return statement of the method which is:

`return [{'parameters': [2022-02-21 00:00:00, 'US/Pacific', 2022-02-23 00:00:00, 'US/Pacific']}]`

`pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'\'parameters\': "(\'2022-02-21 00:00:00\',\'US/Pacific\',\'2022-02-23 00:00:00\',\'US/Pacific\' at line 16')`

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a Python statement, is it possible you're confusing Python and SQL and trying to execute Python code as an SQL statement?